# android.R.string.close_button_text

Tags: android

Почему я могу использовать в проекте строку

```
android.R.string.ok
```

но не могу использовать в том же месте строку

```
android.R.string.close_button_text
```

хотя эти строки ведь находятся в одном файле (values\strings.xml в sdk)?..

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При этом у меня эта строка видна в файле values\strings.xml из sdk, из системных ресурсов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Старайтесь не использовать ресурсы из `android.R`. Гугл рекомендует создавать в своём проекте копию, потому что в будущих версиях ресурс может быть удалён/изменён, что приведёт к ошибкам в приложении. Особенно это касается drawable ресурсов, но применимо и к строкам.

Comment: @DeKaNszn, очень интересно, не видела раньше этой рекомендации... Не могли бы Вы поделиться ссылкой на какой-либо ресурс, где описана эта рекомендация от Гугл?

Comment: про drawable ресурсы: https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_menu.html (предупреждение в разделе Example icons)

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Я думаю, что это можно даже считать ответом на мой вопрос!

Answer (score 2):

Когда вы пишите `android.R.string`, вы обращаетесь к системным ресурсам

Для того, чтобы получить строковый ресурс вашего приложения из директории `values/strings`, вы должны использовать `R.string`

В вашем случае, нужно писать `R.string.close_button_text`

---

P.S. с ресурсом `android.R.string.ok` вам просто повезло - [такой](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.string.html#ok) есть в системе

Comment: У меня эта строка видна в файле values\strings.xml из sdk, из системных ресурсов (обновила пост, добавила скриншот).

Answer (score 2):

Вполне возможно, что Google специально заблокировали доступ к этому ресурсу (причины неизвестны) с помощью метода, описанного в [офф документации](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/android-library.html#PrivateResources)